# What is the necessity of $\epsilon$-net?

Tags: metric-spaces, compactness, nets

What is the use of introducing the concepts of $\epsilon$-net in compactness.We know that if a set $A$ is totally bounded then for each $\epsilon>0$ ,there exists a finite $\epsilon$-nets in $A$.So,what is the use of defining it separately?Is it helpful in some other aspect?

Comment: For one thing, it can be used as the basis for one way of measuring the size of compact sets, especially in infinite dimensional spaces (see *Kolmogorov Entropy* [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3517466/13130)). It can also be a useful tool in some proofs, and in fact I used $\epsilon$-nets in the proof of *Note 6* on p. 96 [here](https://www.jstor.org/stable/44152829).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works out that a metric space $X$ is compact iff it’s complete and totally bounded, so it’s important.